# Sending SMS once with arduino GPRS SIM900 if an input is HIGH

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, c

I faced a problem to send 1 SMS if an input is HIGH and if it is LOW no SMS will be sent. The code not working, just sends SMS when I turn the GPRS on and after that nothing happens.

Please check this link to see the code : [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818894/send-sms-for-1-time-with-arduino-gprs-sim900-if-an-iput-is-high)

Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: Please avoid laziness and repost the complete question here, rather than asking everyone to go to another SE site to look at it; thanks.

Comment: `repost the complete question here` - AKA cross-posting. [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) - answer is NO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach an interrupt to the pin which is getting HIGH and then the function connected to the interrupt will have the code to send the SMS.

Just init the GPRS with connecting to the network then just wait for the interrupt to send anything.